# OneToMany jpa relation using javafx ListProperty

Tags: jpa, javafx

How to write OneToMany relation in jpa entity class using javafx listproperty
I tried this:

```
private final ListProperty<Bill> bills = new SimpleListProperty<>();

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Bill.class, mappedBy = "invoice")
public ObservableList getBills() {
    return bills.get();
}

public void setBills(ObservableList value) {
    bills.set(value);
}

public ListProperty billsProperty() {
    return bills;
}
```

getting error : " oneTomany attribute type should be [java.util.colletion, java.util.List]

Comment: So use java type "java.util.Collection" or "java.util.List"!

Comment: That will work. But how to use observable listproperty

Comment: You cannot unless one of the JPA providers provides support for that type. Not part of the JPA spec, and minority interest, so doubt you will get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use List rather than ObservableList from the getter and setter functions.

```
private final ListProperty<Bill> bills = new SimpleListProperty<>();

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Bill.class, mappedBy = "invoice")
public List getBills() {
    return bills.get();
}

public void setBills(List value) {
    bills.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(value));
}

public ListProperty billsProperty() {
    return bills;
}
```